# how to see keys member of illustration hashtable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am customizing ADFS 3.0 login page with PowerShell command.

I am able to apply iilustration image with following command.

```
Set-AdfsWebTheme -TargetName default -Illustration @{path="C:\ADFS\bg.jpg"}
```

But I want use property background-repeat= repeat-x but I don't know the key name of this hashtable.

Can any body no how to use this property?

Comment: Did you read the [help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479318.aspx) page from Technet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Illustration` parameter does not accept CSS directives like `background-repeat` or the likes.

From the [TechNet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479318.aspx):

### -Illustration `<Hashtable[]>`

> Specifies an array of Hashtable objects that specify illustrations by using two string keys: **Locale** and **Path**.
>   Locale is a CultureInfo object. Path is a file path. If you do not specify a locale, Locale refers to the invariant locale.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I am able to apply backgrouund-repeat using css to apply theme to adfs login page.